# During which period Vishnu incarnated as Matsya to save vedas?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, matsya

Lord Vishnu took matsya avatar during the end of 6th Manu and saved Vaivaswata from pralaya. But there's also a story of Vishnu taking Matsya avatar to save vedas. When did that happen? Is there a huge timeline difference between the two avatars?

Comment: My bad... I read that half way and asked this question... later now only found Destroyer has the answer @Sarvabhouma!